# Consuming Web Services in Ruby that use reserved words as field names

Tags: ruby, soap

I'm attempting to consume a WebService where one of the complex types in the WSDL has a field name that uses a Ruby reserved word.  When I call a method returning one of these complex types and attempt to access the data, I get an error.

How can I consume this web service that uses a reserved word in Ruby?

The relevant section of the WSDL is:

```
<s:complexType name="someObject">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="field1" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="field2" type="s:boolean"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="field3" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="class" type="s:string"/> 
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="field4" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
  <s:attribute form="unqualified" name="type" type="s:string"/>
</s:complexType>
```

Here is the XML coming back from my method call:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <MethodCallResponse>
      <MethodCallResult>
        <results>
          <object type="someObject">
            <field1>Whatever</field1>
            <field2>true</field2>
            <field3>TCP</field3>
            <class>CLIENT</class>
          </object>
        </results>
      </MethodCallResult>
    </MethodCallResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The error:

```
undefined method `class_eval' for "CLIENT":String
```

I am using ruby 1.8.7-p302.

Comment: I believe a good solution is to ditch soap/wsdlDriver and use soap4r

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like the [BlankState method](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BlankSlate.rdoc). The idea is that you create an encapsulating class for your data that undefines some the methods that are colliding with the poorly named types.